# Решил задачу по PHP но не совсем верно. Помогите разобраться что не так

Tags: php

Решил задачу по PHP но решение не совсем удовлетворяет условию, пока слабо понимаю язык, подскажите в какую сторону копать.
условие:
Реализовать функцию squareTrapeze($a). $a – массив результата выполнения функции createTrapeze(). Результат ее выполнение: в исходный массив для каждой тройки чисел добавляется дополнительный ключ s, содержащий результат расчета площади трапеции со сторонами a и b, и высотой c.
вот моя функция

```
function squareTrapeze($a)
{
    $result = array_map(function($item) {
      $item['s'] = ($item['a'] + $item['b']) * $item['c'] / 2; // считаем и записываем
      return $item;
    }, $a);
    
    return $result;
}

$arr3 = squareTrapeze($arr2);
print_r($arr3);
```

вот такой ответ на решение я получил:

> Функция squareTrapeze($a) - по условию в исходный массив для каждой тройки чисел добавляется дополнительный ключ s, т.е. использование ссылки на переменную

Comment: Судя по описанию, ты не изменяешь элементы старого массива. Вроде бы php копирует массивы.

Comment: вам не надо делать map, это в принципе модифицирует входной массив и предполагает возврат некой копии. Написано, что модифицировать надо входящий. То есть передать его по ссылке, и добавить туда ключ, в цикле или array_walk. проще конечно, первое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь не нужно использовать array_map, потому что нужно изменить исходный массив, а не создавать новый из исходного. Намного проще сделать то что хочет автор задачи примерно так

```
function squareTrapeze($a){
    foreach( $a as &$item ) {
        $item['s'] = ($item['a'] + $item['b']) * $item['c'] / 2;
    }

    return $a;
}
```